# Can't segue from UICollectionReusableView

Tags: uicollectionview, segue, uicollectionreusableview

I have UICollectionView and Header.I have textfield and image.I did try push segue working fine.But I need to call segue!
Any help will be appreciate

Header.h

```
@interface HeaderRV : UICollectionReusableView
@property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet UITextField *searchField;
@property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet UILabel *titleLabel;
- (IBAction)backButton:(id)sender;


@end
```

---

Header.m

```
@implementation HeaderRV

- (id)initWithFrame:(CGRect)frame
{
self = [super initWithFrame:frame];
if (self) {
    // Initialization code
}
return self;
}
- (IBAction)backButton:(id)sender {

if ([self.searchField isEditing]) {
    [self.searchField resignFirstResponder];
}
else{
    //segue need to be here
}

}

@end
```

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem as you do. It's actually quite tricky because you can have done "perform segue in collectionHeaderView" perfectly in an empty project(I tried). I found the key to this problem is **your RootVC of navigation controller isn't the initial VC of the app**.
  You can get around this by adding the lines below in your .m file that presents the rootVC of navigation controller.

```
- (IBAction)next:(id)sender {
[theRootVCinNavigationController] *vc = [self.storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"[your identifier]"];
UINavigationController *navigationController = [[UINavigationController alloc] initWithRootViewController:[theRootVCinNavigationController]];
[self presentViewController:navigationController animated:YES completion:nil];
}
```

References:

1. [How to add an UINavigationController to an UIViewController presented as Modal](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15058644/how-to-add-an-uinavigationcontroller-to-an-uiviewcontroller-presented-as-modal)
2. https://developer.apple.com/Library/ios/documentation/WindowsViews/Conceptual/ViewControllerCatalog/Chapters/NavigationControllers.html        (search for "Creating a navigation interface")